# stopping a handler thread button

Tags: java, android, android-handler, java-threads

Every 5 sec I want to current latitude longitude to the web application in Android app. if the user login to the app in that we using user logs by placing a button's. If the user hits log out button I need to stop the handler thread current run on same activity page by a different button (Log in )

I have done everything but while stopping the threads my application get crashed

if the user hit login button it automatically sends the data for every 5 sec

```
private void techlocation() {
    handler = new Handler ();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) User_deatils .this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // Choose your accuracy requirement.
    locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(User_deatils.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(User_deatils.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 8000, 10, (LocationListener) User_deatils .this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 8000, 10, (LocationListener) User_deatils .this);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


    if (location != null) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    }
    handler.postDelayed(runLocation, 5000);


}
```

This is the runnable threads sends data to server-side

```
public Runnable runLocation = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
            longitude = String.valueOf(lon);
            arrLat.add(latitude);
            arrLng.add(longitude);
 User_deatils.this.handler.postDelayed(User_deatils.this.runLocation, 50000);
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(this);
            Log.e("msg", "new" + handler);
    }
}
```

log in button

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               .// SaveButtonState("b3");
                  techlocation(); // calling handler threads

            }
        });
```

log out button

```
b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(runLocation);
  }
        });
```

Comment: post logcat here also

Comment: You may be getting crash in the case when you are logging out before pressing b3. It happens because your handler is not initialized yet. To handle it just check whether your handler is null or not before removing its callbacks

Comment: @p.mathew13  you absolutely right . when i try to click the button my app gets crashed. thanks bro . just few's day back i got a error .

Comment: @p.mathew13 i need to initialized handler inside on the button rigth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To start runnable and do work every 5 seconds do this.**

Declare `runnable` this way with a `boolean`.

// flag that should be set true if handler should stop

```
 boolean mStopHandler = false;
private Handler mHandler;

//initialize runnable in oncreate()
mHandler=new Handler();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do your stuff here 

        if (!mStopHandler) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    }
};
```

> Call this to start this `runnable` on button `click()`

```
// start runnable
mHandler.post(runnable);
```

> And finally use this to stop runnable

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```